# asp.net showing model popup from menu menu

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have asp.net menu control in master page and requirment is to show moedel popup by clicking on it. Can u plz guide me on this issue ?

I couldn't get any way to execute javascript code by clicking asp.net menu. Please guid and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your JavaScript to NavigateUrl as example below!

```
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Root" Value="Root">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Item1" Value="Item1" NavigateUrl="javascript:alert('Hello from JavaScript!');"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: thanks StefanE, actually I am not doing databinding. My hard coding menues. Please advice.